# Anyone have a link for IN-DEPTH ArcGIS Toolbox documentation

Tags: python, arctoolbox

I am looking for in-depth links for documentation on parameter data types for adding custom scripts to a custom toolbox.  For example, a parameter data type "Extract Values".  What does this do?  What configuration options are, there and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arcgis 10 Desktop help: [Data types for geoprocessing tool parameters](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/002t/002t00000003000000.htm)

pdf of docs -- http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/002t/pdf/Geoprocessing_data_types.pdf

Comment: Though "Extract Values" isn't there...good thing...then how would I fill my need to click buttons erratically!